# How to Make SQL Query that excludes rows without all parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-mysqlidb

I have a search box that I give the user to put in key words they want to search for. On submit, I split the words in the input box (if multiple) into an array and perform a query for each individual word. With SQL I can get results that have at least one of the values, the problem is that I want to only get rows that have at least all of the parameters in one column or another.

```
public function employeeSearchAction()
    {
        if ($this->user_permissions < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        // split search string into array based on spaces
        if ($this->data != '') {
            $searchParams = explode(' ', trim($this->data));
            // get any rows with any one of these values in them
            foreach ($searchParams as $s) {
                $this->db->orWhere('user_firstname', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_lastname', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_email1', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_phn_1', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_phn_2', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_phn_3', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                // $this->db->orWhere('user_address1', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_position', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_type', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                $this->db->orWhere('user_division', '%'.$s.'%', 'like');
                // $this->db->orWhere('user_position', $s);
                // $this->db->orWhere('user_type', $s);
                // $this->db->orWhere('user_division', $s);
            }
            $this->db->having('owner_id', $this->owner_id);
            $binaryArray = array_fill(0, sizeof($searchParams), 0);
            $results = $this->db->get('tblusers');
            $filtered = [];
            // filter rows to ensure that all rows have every parameter
            foreach ($results as $r) {
                $binaryArray = array_fill(0, sizeof($searchParams), 0);
                foreach ($binaryArray as $key=>$b) {
                    if (strpos(strtolower($r['user_firstname']), strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos(strtolower($r['user_lastname']), strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos($r['user_email1'], strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos($r['user_phn_1'], strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos($r['user_phn_2'], strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos($r['user_phn_3'], strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos(strtolower($r['user_position']), strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos(strtolower($r['user_type']), strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false ||
                  strpos(strtolower($r['user_division']), strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false
                  // strpos($r['user_address1'], strtolower($searchParams[$key])) !== false
                ) {
                        $binaryArray[$key] = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (!in_array(0, $binaryArray)) {
                    $filtered[] = $r;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->db->where('owner_id', $this->owner_id);
            $filtered = $this->db->get('tblusers');
        }
        foreach ($filtered as $r) {
            $user_phn_1 = $r['user_phn_1'] == '' ? 'N/A' : '<a href="tel:+1'.$r['user_phn_1'].'">'.preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $r['user_phn_1']).'</a>';
            $user_phn_2 = $r['user_phn_2'] == '' ? 'N/A' : '<a href="tel:+1'.$r['user_phn_2'].'">'.$r['user_phn_2'].'</a>';
            $user_position = $r['user_position'] == '' ? 'N/A' : $r['user_position'];
            $user_type = $r['user_type'] == '' ? 'N/A' : $r['user_type'];
            $user_division = $r['user_division'] == '' ? 'N/A' : $r['user_division'];
            $user_email1 = $r['user_email1'] == '' ? 'N/A' : '<a href="mailto:'.$r['user_email1'].'">'.$r['user_email1'].'</a>';
            $user_address1 = $r['user_address1'] == '' ? 'N/A' : '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$r['user_address1'].'">'.$r['user_address1'].'</a>';
            $user_firstname = $r['user_firstname'] == '' ? 'N/A' : $r['user_firstname'];
            $user_lastname = $r['user_lastname'] == '' ? 'N/A' : $r['user_lastname'];
            $r['is_ready'] != 1 ? $user_firstname .=  ' <i title="Employee is not ready to work." class="orange fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>' : '';
            echo "
            <div class='search-form_row-container'>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
                 <i class='fas fa-file-signature'>
                 <span class='results-text results-text--name'>$user_lastname $user_firstname</span>
                 </i>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
               <i class='fas fa-phone'>
                <span class='results-text results-text--phone'>{$user_phn_1}</span>
               </i>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
                <a href='/includes/sql/store/users/curr_user.php?id={$r['user_id']}&goto=/users/user_profile_main.php'>
                 <i class='fas fa-link'>
                 <span class='results-text results-text--edit'>View Profile</span>
                 </i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
                 <i class='fas fa-suitcase-rolling'>
                 <span class='results-text results-text--position'>$user_position</span>
                 </i>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
                 <i class='fas fa-map-marker-alt'>
                 <span class='results-text results-text--type'>$user_type</span>
                 </i>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
                 <i class='fas fa-i-cursor'></i>
                 <span class='results-text results-text--division'>$user_division</span>
                 </i>
              </div>
          </div>
        ";
        }
    }
```

What I have functions as it should but I can't help noticing how unbelievably ugly and inefficient it is. Looking at the code you'll know I'm not using raw queries, I'm using https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class Mysqlidb. If you'd like to forego phrasing your answer in that format, it's fine, this library can use raw queries. Any help is appreciated. I just would rather only retrieve records that hold all of the parameters instead of records that hold at least one and then filtering them out with PHP.

Edit: My intent is to be able to just do with this SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a query that fetches data for all users. For each user, you need to check if that user's data contains each keyword. If the users data contains all the keywords, then the user can be included in the search results.

So you need to have nested loops. The outer loop checks each user. The inner loop checks each keyword in the users data. If the users data contains all keywords, then include the user in the search results. If one of the keywords is not present in the users data, then break the inner loop and check the next user.